# Find second partial derivative of G by x where $G(x,y) = F(x,y,f(x,y))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Let $G(x,y)=F(x,y,f(x,y))$. I want to find $\dfrac{\partial^2G}{\partial x^2}$ in terms of partial derivative of $F$ and $f$. I am not sure if my solution is correct as it looks different from the one in my textbook. The below is my solution: Put $z = f(x,y)$

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^2} &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z} \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right) \\
&= \dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial z}
\end{align*}

The solution in the textbook is:
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial z} + \dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z\partial x} \right) + \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z^2}$$

Comment: Your differentiation of the terms isn't right. And the reason you made the error is because you didn't use the chain rule (because you didn't explicitly write down the points of evaluation). It should be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x, y, f(x, y))}+\cdots\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation makes a distinction between the differential operator ($\frac{\partial~~}{\partial x}$, which takes place with respect to $x$ where-ever it occurs in the *composition* to which it is being applied) and the partial differential expression (which is made with respect to $x$ as an argument of the *function*, while holding remaining arguments constrained (even if they too contain $x$)).

Thus the chain rule is implemented as:

$$\small\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}F &= \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}\\[1ex]\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}&=\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x~^2}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z~\partial x}\\[1ex]\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}&=\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x~\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z~^2}\end{align}$$

So...taking it slow

$$\small\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x~^2}&=\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}F\right)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x~}\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}\right)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x~^2}\cdot\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}\tag 1\\[1ex]&=\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x~^2}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z~\partial x}\right)+\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x~^2}\cdot\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x~\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z~^2}\right)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x~^2}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z~\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x~\partial z}\right)+\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x~^2}\cdot\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}+\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\cdot\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z~^2}\tag 2\end{align}$$